# PHP: Converting curly braces with square braces

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with JSON format on my controller output. It nothings wrong with it, but I just need to change it into a different form of JSON.

My JSON was like this:

```
{"data": [{"function_name": "Y", "register_id": "1", "age": 26, "contract_from": "01-07-18", "contract_until": "31-12-99", "worked_hours": 1, "days": 9, "costs": 7, "hourly_rate": 2}]}
```

and my controller:

```
public function list_test(){
  $filter = $this->input->post('filter');
  $query  = $this->db->query("select * from hc where contract_from = '".$filter."'")->result();
  $data['data'] = $query;
  print_r(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

How could I do to replace curly braces inside data to be swapped with square braces?

My expected output:

```
{"data": [["Y", "1", "26", "01-07-18", "31-12-99", "1", "9","7", "2"]]}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your expected output is invalid JSON (check with https://jsonlint.com/).  You cannot have arrays with named elements.

Comment: There are no _"different form of JSON"_. JSON is a single format. When you convert an array to json, it can either become `{"foo": "bar"}` (converting an associative array), or `["foo", "bar"]` (indexed array). But having `["foo": "bar"]` is not valid JSON. Key/value pairs are objects using `{}` and lists are just `[]` that can contain a value, but no name/key.

Comment: That is invalid JSON. You could do a [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the output if you need to replace {} with [] for some reason though.

Comment: @NigelRen oh I'm very sorry sir, I've been edited my expected output. There was a human error in typing it earlier.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm very sorry sir, I've been edited my expected output. There was a human error in typing it earlier

Comment: What are you planning of doing with the data? The expected result would be hard to use since there's nothing explaining what the value actually represents. Your current output looks like the ideal format, if you ask me.

Comment: here it is sir @MagnusEriksson https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: I want to place my array into datatables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it still is the best result to get (why remove useful information like column names).

You would need to process each row to remove the keys by using `array_values()`...

```
$data = ['data' => array_map("array_values", $query) ];
```

I've also changed the way the `$data` array is created so that you know it is initialised properly.